# Collectionview interactive cell swapping

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, ios9

I have implemented a collection view as described [here](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/104-interactive-collection-view-re-ordering). As you can see, it uses the interactive re-ordering of cells of collectionview provided in iOS 9. But the problem is, I cannot control the reordering of cells.

Say the cells are like this -

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
```

I want to swap only cell 6 and 4. So after re-ordering the cells will be

```
1  2  3  6
5  4  7  8
9  10 11 12
```

Here, In the tutorial, at the beginning of the program, the collection view is like this - 
[image]

If I put **Starbuck** on top of **Rose Tyler** this happens -

[image]

Notice that **Sarah Connor** has Place of **Starbuck**.

I want to control the reordering of cells so that here **Rose Tyler** and **Starbuck** positions will be swapped.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution will be to implement your own interactive cell ordering behaviour by simply moving the cell along the pan in screen and swap when gesture ends on another cell's location (with your own animation and data source update ). Here is a working sample:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var arr: [String] = (0...100).map { return "\($0)" }

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView =  {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv: UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Cell.id)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width/3.5, height: 100)
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
        return cv
    }()

    lazy var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))

    private var movingCell: MovingCell?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view = collectionView
    }

    @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        var cell: (UICollectionViewCell?, IndexPath?) {
            guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionView)),
                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else { return (nil, nil) }
            return (cell, indexPath)
        }

        switch(gesture.state) {

        case .began:
            movingCell = MovingCell(cell: cell.0, originalLocation: cell.0?.center, indexPath: cell.1)
            break
        case .changed:

            /// Make sure moving cell floats above its siblings.
            movingCell?.cell.layer.zPosition = 100
            movingCell?.cell.center = gesture.location(in: gesture.view!)

            break
        case .ended:

            swapMovingCellWith(cell: cell.0, at: cell.1)
            movingCell = nil
        default:
            movingCell?.reset()
            movingCell = nil
        }
    }

    func swapMovingCellWith(cell: UICollectionViewCell?, at indexPath: IndexPath?) {
        guard let cell = cell, let moving = movingCell else {
            movingCell?.reset()
            return
        }

        // update data source
        arr.swapAt(moving.indexPath.row, indexPath!.row)

        // swap cells
        animate(moving: moving.cell, to: cell)
    }

    func animate(moving movingCell: UICollectionViewCell, to cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
        longPressGesture.isEnabled = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            movingCell.center = cell.center
            cell.center = movingCell.center
        }) { _ in
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            self.longPressGesture.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: Cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Cell.id, for: indexPath) as! Cell
        cell.titleLable.text = arr[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    private struct MovingCell {
        let cell: UICollectionViewCell
        let originalLocation: CGPoint
        let indexPath: IndexPath

        init?(cell: UICollectionViewCell?, originalLocation: CGPoint?, indexPath: IndexPath?) {
            guard cell != nil, originalLocation != nil, indexPath != nil else { return nil }
            self.cell = cell!
            self.originalLocation = originalLocation!
            self.indexPath = indexPath!
        }

        func reset() {
            cell.center = originalLocation
        }
    }

    final class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
        static let id: String = "CellId"

        lazy var titleLable: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.bounds.width, height: 30))

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            addSubview(titleLable)
            titleLable.backgroundColor = .green
            backgroundColor = .white
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but in my case there is not fixced layout

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. If cell sizes are calculated based on indexPath, e.g. let's say even row indices have twice height than odd rows, The items will resize according to their new indexPath. If size depends on model, the item will keep their size no matter where they're moved. This is the logical behaviour but if you want something else, thats another question :) Feel free to explain and I'll take a look.

Comment: i want total 5 column 3 row collection view in this all cell height equals and width of 1st, 2nd, 4th & 5th column width is same as height means in square formate, and the 3rd column cell never replace to any with any other

Comment: let me try what happen!

Comment: sorry, can you give me a minute

Comment: Ok, to prevent moving every 3rd row, inside handleLongGesture `var cell: (UICollectionView?, IndexPath?)` add this code: ```if indexPath.row == 3 || (indexPath.row - 3) % 5 == 0 {
                return (nil, nil)
            }```

No magic number here :) , 3 is to say every 3rd row and 5 is because you have 5 columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161502/discussion-between-lukas-and-kiran-sarvaiya).

Comment: @Lukas can we achive this using UICollectionview dragInteraction? i follow this tutorial https://hackernoon.com/drag-it-drop-it-in-collection-table-ios-11-6bd28795b313

Answer (score 1):

For reordering of collection view item we need to add Long press gesture on collection view . and for reordering the collection View item with a particular indexPath, UICollectionViewDelegate provide the "targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt" method.
And for getting the complete tutorial you follow this one [Reordering CollectionView Item](https://developerfly.com/use-collectionviewdatasource-method-moveitemat-reordering-collectionview-cell-ios-swift-4/)

Comment: sorry but i don't want like this, i just source and destination position swap just dont want reorder collectionview

Comment: Ok i am understand your problem. but i think for this question have not any direct solution , you can move a collection View item with "targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt" method at particular position . and update you data array and at last reload the collection view like this .

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        arrayCellTitle.swapAt(sourceIndexPath.item, destinationIndexPath.item)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

Comment: but i dont want interactive animation also i just need simple animation

Comment: can we disable interactive animation

Comment: interactive animation means Reordering animation. I think its not possible.

Comment: yes i want to disable and just show smooth drag and drop animation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161289/discussion-between-kiran-sarvaiya-and-aman19ish).

Answer (score 1):

I would do in the following steps...

**1-st Step** Create a model like this

```
class CrewMembersModel {
    var name: String?
    var position: Int?

    fileprivate init (name: String, position: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
    }

    static var crewMembersDataList: [CrewMembersModel]? = nil

    class func getMembersList() -> [CrewMembersModel] {
        if (self.crewMembersDataList == nil) {
            self.crewMembersDataList = [CrewMembersModel]()
            self.crewMembersDataList?.append(CrewMembersModel(name: "Sam Carter", position: 0))
            self.crewMembersDataList?.append(CrewMembersModel(name: "Dana Scully", position: 1))
            self.crewMembersDataList?.append(CrewMembersModel(name: "Rose Taylor", position: 2))
            self.crewMembersDataList?.append(CrewMembersModel(name: "Sarah Conor", position: 3))
            self.crewMembersDataList?.append(CrewMembersModel(name: "Starbuck", position: 4))
            self.crewMembersDataList?.append(CrewMembersModel(name: "River Tam", position: 5))
            self.crewMembersDataList?.append(CrewMembersModel(name: "Sarah Jane", position: 6))

        }
        return crewMembersDataList!.sorted(by: { $0.position! < $1.position!})
    }
}
```

*Please Note* 
Here you can add other properties of your model like image, etc...

**2-nd Step** Get model list in `ViewController` `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.crewMembersDataList = CrewMembersModel.getMembersList()
```

**3-rd Step** In `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` parse model data

```
let crewMembersData: CrewMembersModel = self.crewMembersDataList[indexPath.row - 1]
cell.name = crewMembersData.name!
```

And finally in 4-th step whenever you made changes change the positions of selected cells and call collectionView.reloadData()

```
func changePositions(selectedModelOne: CrewMembersModel, selectedModelTwo: CrewMembersModel) {
    let tmpPosition = selectedModelOne.position!
    selectedModelOne.position = selectedModelTwo.position!
    selectedModelTwo.position = tmpPosition

    self.crewMembersDataList.sorted(by: { $0.position! < $1.position!})
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

*Please Note* I didn't check entire code, might be some syntax issues

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you're only moving one object, or in your case Starbuck.

When you do that the list is going to reorder itself; Based on that Rose Tyler will logically be in the position that you've shown.

If you think of it as a queue for a ride in a theme park then the behaviour you've shown makes perfect sense. Sam, Dana and Rose are first second and third in the queue and Sarah, Starbuck and River are fourth, fifth and sixth. If Rose then lets Starbuck go in front of her then Rose is then fourth in line and Sarah is now fifth.

To get what you want you'll need to keep a reference of where Rose is in the list and where Starbuck is in the list. You'll then need to move each person that needs to move one by one rather than just moving Starbuck as you're doing currently.

Comment: Yes that is logical if you think about the queue. But If I want to swap the position of them, that should be possible as well. Think that, they are switching places. The problem is that I dont know how the collection view is re-ordering its cells. I need to know the method that is actively re-ordering the cells as the cells are moved. I could not find any.

Comment: do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
UICollectionView *collection;
MSMutableArray *datasource;
NSIndexPath *from = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
NSIndexPath *to = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0];

// swap animated
[collection performBatchUpdates:^{
    // To avoid problems, you should update your data model inside the updates block 
    [datasource exchangeObjectAtIndex:from.item withObjectAtIndex:to.item];
    // for swap need two move operations
    [collection moveItemAtIndexPath:from toIndexPath:to];
    [collection moveItemAtIndexPath:to toIndexPath:from];
    // no need to update the moved cells because the content has not changed
    //[collection reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```